# i have been getting this error frequently about the opt() function in which package is it in? how can i handle it?

Tags: r

this is the error

> q + geom_point()+opts(title="geom_point")
>   Error in opts(title = "geom_point") : could not find function "opts"
>
> q + geom_point()+opts(title="geom_point")
>   Error in opts(title = "geom_point") : could not find function "opts"

Comment: have you loaded `ggplot2`.  It is a deprecated function.  You may need `theme`

Comment: yeah, i have loaded the ggplot2, but i still get the error, i don't understand why the opts() function doesn't work

Comment: This function was long deprecated.  See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/opts)

Comment: how will i recode the opts() function using those theme functions?

Comment: You just replace the `opts` with `theme`.  Look at the vignettes of `ggplot2`